# Simplest implementation of MVVM + Repository in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mvvm, repository-pattern, state-management

I read through a dozen articles about different state management libraries and architecture patterns but I still have trouble with it.

### **My main question is:**

What would be a bare minimum implementation example of the MVVM pattern + a repository in Flutter?

Meaning, with the least possible amount of packages used and extra classes created, beyond the VM and Repo.

---

### **What I am trying to achieve:**

Basically just this data flow: `Repository -> ViewModel -> View` (and other way around).
In more detail, it would be:

1. Read data from DB in repository. When done, notify listeners (ViewModels) that data is loaded.
2. ViewModel receives update of data, it in turn *also notifies listener* (View) about new data.
3. Lastly, the View/UI receives the data and displays it.
4. (And other way around, user interacts with UI -> triggers function in VM -> triggers some function in repo to update DB)

I want to separate the logic by topic, e.g. in a self-help app I had *challenges* and *self-affirmations* which would then each receive their own repo and VM. But that repo & VM would then contain ***all*** related variables & methods for this topic.

In SwiftUI I did it like this:

```
class ChallengeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var challengeRepository = ChallengeRepository()
    @Published private(set) var challenges: [Challenge] = []
    // ...other published variables related to challenges
    // Set of cancellables to keep listeners running
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        // Set up a listener for each variable individually
        challengeRepository.$allChallenges
            .sink { [weak self] repoChallenges in
                self?.challenges = repoChallenges ?? []
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)

        // ...other listeners for each relevant variable
    }

    // etc...
}
```

The VM listens to updates from the repo and stores this data "in-between", then the UI listens to the VM. So basically have the VM be subscribed to the Repo in a similar way that the UI is subscribed to the VM. Kind of like a chain.

---

### Doing this in Flutter:

Many tutorials or explanations for this topic focus only on the connection between UI and ViewModel, which is simple enough. But what if I have one more piece in this chain (repository)?

There seem to be 3 popular ways of architecture & state management: provider, riverpod or bloc.

- **Provider** seems to be simple enough, but I've only seen it being used for simple `UI <-> ViewModel` connections
- **Riverpod** seems to be enabling what I want, having a chain of providers listening to each other
- **BloC** seems to be basically MVVM just called differently, so it must be a good fit too

Now my problem is, while provider seems to be too simplistic, the latter two seem to completely blow project complexity out of proportion (for a small project).

Reading examples of e.g. riverpod, it looks like you have to create a ***class for every single value that can be updated***:

```
final filterTypeProvider = StateProvider<FilterType>((ref) => FilterType.none);
final todosProvider = StateNotifierProvider<TodoList, List<Todo>>((ref) => TodoList());
```

This seems completely overkill for a smaller app. I don't want to create 20 abstract classes or factories. I simply want one repo & VM per topic.

Comment: I fail to see a specific question. You are mixing many things at once in this question and I'm eager to vote for a close as "Need more focus" or that this is "Opinion-based" because "simplest way" depends on preference. I see no reason why e.g. using one (1) repo, with one (1) or many (N) blocs/cubits and then one (1) or many (M) widgets would be either too complex or too simple. It is completely up to you? Then if you want to yield/stream the data from the repo to the cubits/blocs or if you let the UI ask for the data via a cubits/blocs then common repo, is completely up to you.

Comment: @RobertSandberg Yeah I probably got a little bogged down in all of this, my main question here can be rephrased as "what is the bare minimum implementation of the MVVM pattern + a repository in Flutter". Without getting too hung up on all the libraries and options.

Comment: @RobertSandberg I updated the question. I hope this part makes it less opinion based and gives it objective answering criteria: _"with the least possible amount of packages used and extra classes created, beyond the VM and Repo."_

Comment: It is still a pretty broad question. I mean you can do it without any extra packages at all and just go for e.g. InheritedWidget. But (I guess) most production grade apps go for something like riverpod or bloc. The bare minimum depends on the complexity of the use case. Like, it depends on how you want the data to flow through the app. Meaning, should the repo always stream data to listeners, or should the views fetch data when needed. I'll write an answer, but it will probably be too general for you to like :) But that is because I find your question very general :)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-coded, using e.g. `flutter_bloc`:

```
class YourCubit extends Cubit<SomeStateHoldingStuff> {
  YourCubit (this.repo) : super(SomeStateHoldingStuff.initial());
  final YourRepo repo;
  StreamSubscription<Stuff> sub;

  Future<void> getStuff() async {
    sub = repo.getStuff().listen((data) {
      // translate data from repo to something for the UI if you want,
      // or just pass the data raw to update the state if you want
      emit(newState(data));
    })
  }
}
```

In this example you would use a `BlocBuilder` to build and react to changes from the repo. You could make the state `SomeStateHoldingStuff` contain "all" the data from the repo if you want, and in the UI filter when each `BlocBuilder` should rebuild.

But this is just one example, You can surely do this in a hundred different ways. E.g. by using Streams in the bloc/cubit. Same approach can be done using Riverpod. Having a provider for the repo with a method that streams/yields data, to one, or many other providers that act as your VM.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I think what made me see it as "too complex" was exactly that `Cubit<SomeStateHoldingStuff>` part. It makes it look like each event needs its own abstract Cubit state that I can then extend. And putting all of the stuff into one such state feels like misusing the concept. Maybe I just don't understand it well enough yet. I will experiment a little and then maybe I can evaluate this better :)

Comment: Well the `SomeStateHoldingStuff` is basically your view model. So that is the thing that your UI should react to. If the UI is to be agnostic about the repo and all business logic I don't see a way of making it any more simple

Comment: If you don't want the bloc between the repo, and the UI, you could instead just use a StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder in the UI hooked up directly to the repository

Comment: Furthermore, the `SomeStateHoldingStuff` could contain your `var challenges: [Challenge] = []` etc. etc

Comment: The extension of Cubit is like the Swift extension of ObservableObject. So it is very similar in many cases

Comment: You're right, I think I just got scared off of it a little because of how it looks and assumed more complexity than it has. In the end it seems to do exactly what I wanted.